# SQL DATE FUNCITON

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I write an SQL statement to determine when the next Friday occurs after a specific calendar date? For example 01-March-2018

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please post your code/query you have tried so far , and where you are facing the issue ..

Comment: Is it necessary to get the Friday from SQL instead of any other application level?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '2018-03-01' + interval (6 - DAYOFWEEK('2018-03-01')) day
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/27439)